# Cordova build crashing upon adding FileChooser plugin

Tags: android, cordova

Since Google in their infinite wisdom decided to remove file upload support from Android 4.4, I've been trying to figure out how to add a file chooser to an app that I am writing.

I added the FileChooser plugin by cdibened [found here](https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser), but every time I try to build the Android version, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
 error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile faile
d; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

C:\xampp\htdocs\CourseworkApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\xampp\htdocs\Cour
seworkApp\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant
-gen
Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\CourseworkApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Comman
d failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)`
```

This error only occurs when I add this plugin, as soon as I remove it, it compiles perfectly.

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why this error occurs and any suggestions on how I could fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't seem to be available on PhoneGap Build by default. You can browse through the available plugins [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins). There seems to no plugins with word *Chooser* on their names.

Comment: Apologies, I should have added a link to the plugin in the question. https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

Comment: @DeclanGreally: It still doesn't seem to be available on PhoneGap Build.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for an alternative plugin that would allow me to pick a file?

Comment: That depends highly based on what it would need to exactly do. Please ask another question about that since it clearly out of scope for this question.

Comment: @sanfor, now you can add plugins from other sources to phonegap build, such us github.

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Only if you pay for it and thus the wording _by default_ on my answer.

Comment: well, if he has added the plugin, he must have paid then.

Comment: AFAIK he added it to his _config.xml_, not to the PGB.

Comment: @sanfor, I've just read the phonegap build plan prices and the free plan allows you to use third party plugins from anywhere https://build.phonegap.com/plans.

Comment: @jcesarmobile: And again, someone still needs to have uploaded those and you can only upload, if you have paid. _Upload plugins_ is not available for free.

Comment: Upload PRIVATE plugins is no available for free, but you can upload public plugins to github and use them

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Very well then, how do you upload the plugin? There are 4 options on Plugins page: 3rd Party plugins (only plugins someone has made available), PhoneGap plugins (Cordova's plugins), Your plugins (says _You have no submitted plugins._, related to the next tab) and Submit plugin (_Please upgrade your PhoneGap Build account to submit a plugin. _). So where is the possibility for that?

Comment: You can publish it on plugins.cordova.io using "plugman publish /path/to/your/plugin" http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: Fair enough, if that really does work. Didn't know that there is such a linking.

Comment: Anyway I'm contacting phonegap build team, I uploaded plugins from a free account long time ago, they might have broken something with the update that allowed plugins from plugins.cordova.io

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that plugin requires some changes on the java source code to make it work, and that isn't possible on phonegap build.

As far as I know, there is no other plugin like that, so you have two options:

1. Fork the plugin and add the java changes according to you package

   Configuration

   You will have to import your.package.name.R into the following java files.

   ```
   FileChooser.java 
   FileChooserActivity.java 
   FileListAdapter.java
   FileListFragment.java
   LocalStorageProvider.java
   ```
2. Develop locally instead of using phonegap build, adding the plugin as described on the readme